# how to make delay for hover:after

Tags: html, css, sass

when hover on element I want it to scale(1.2) and then after .6 delay hover for :after

I tried something and its looking like that:

```
.recipes {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 2rem;
            display:flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            justify-content: space-between;
                
            .mb-3 {
                transition: transform .5s ease 0s;
                
                &:hover {
                    transform: scale(1.3);
                    z-index: 2;
                }
                &::after{
                    transition: background-color ease .6s;
                    
                }
                &:hover::after {
                    content: "Click on me for full Recipe";
                    background-color: black;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;

                    display: flex;
                    justify-content: center;
                    align-items: center;
                    font-size: 2rem;
                    color: white;
                    position: absolute;
                    filter: opacity(.85);
                }

            }
```

[image]

I want the black background and the content to be visibale after the transition for scale is finish

for now it it is not doing delay for the :after

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the transition with a keyframe animation and use an [animation-delay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay).